# In apache spark SQL, how to remove the duplicate rows when using collect_list in window function?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below dataframe,

```
+----+-----+----+--------+
|year|month|item|quantity|
+----+-----+----+--------+
|2019|1    |TV  |8       |
|2019|2    |AC  |10      |
|2018|1    |TV  |2       |
|2018|2    |AC  |3       |
+----+-----+----+--------+
```

by using window function I wanted to get below output,

```
val partitionWindow = Window.partitionBy("year").orderBy("month")
val itemsList= collect_list(struct("item", "quantity")).over(partitionWindow)

df.select("year", itemsList as "items")

Expected output:
+----+-------------------+
|year|items              |
+----+-------------------+
|2019|[[TV, 8], [AC, 10]]|
|2018|[[TV, 2], [AC, 3]] |
+----+-------------------+
```

But, when I use window function, there are duplicate rows for each item,

```
Current output:
+----+-------------------+
|year|items              |
+----+-------------------+
|2019|[[TV, 8]]          |
|2019|[[TV, 8], [AC, 10]]|
|2018|[[TV, 2]]          |
|2018|[[TV, 2], [AC, 3]] |
+----+-------------------+
```

I wanted to know which is best way to remove the duplicate rows?

Comment: corrected mistakes in the dataset

Comment: u can use `last` function on `unbounded window` to filter with. or get `row_number()` and then `max` of `row_number` to filter on.

Comment: was actualy a very good question, non udf solution i had with 1issue

Comment: Posted a UDF very simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the interesting part here is that the aggregated list of items is to be sorted by month. So I've written code in three approaches as :

Creating a sample dataset:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
case class data(year : Int, month : Int, item : String, quantity : Int)
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val inputDF = spark.createDataset(Seq(
    data(2018, 2, "AC", 3),
    data(2019, 2, "AC", 10),
    data(2019, 1, "TV", 2),
    data(2018, 1, "TV", 2)
    )).toDF()
```

Approach1: Aggregating month, item and quantiy into list and then sorting the items by month using UDF as:

```
case class items(item : String, quantity : Int)
def getItemsSortedByMonth(itemsRows : Seq[Row]) : Seq[items] = {
    if (itemsRows == null || itemsRows.isEmpty) {
      null
    }
    else {
      itemsRows.sortBy(r => r.getAs[Int]("month"))
      .map(r => items(r.getAs[String]("item"), r.getAs[Int]("quantity")))
    }
  }
val itemsSortedByMonthUDF = udf(getItemsSortedByMonth(_: Seq[Row]))
val outputDF = inputDF.groupBy(col("year"))
    .agg(collect_list(struct("month", "item", "quantity")).as("items"))
    .withColumn("items", itemsSortedByMonthUDF(col("items")))
```

Approach2: Using window functions

```
val monthWindowSpec = Window.partitionBy("year").orderBy("month")
       val rowNumberWindowSpec = Window.partitionBy("year").orderBy("row_number")
        val runningList = collect_list(struct("item", "quantity")). over(rowNumberWindowSpec)
    val tempDF = inputDF
      // using row_number for continuous ranks if there are multiple items in the same month
      .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(monthWindowSpec))
      .withColumn("items", runningList)
    .drop("month", "item", "quantity")

    tempDF.persist()
    val yearToSelect = tempDF.groupBy("year").agg(max("row_number").as("row_number"))

    val outputDF = tempDF.join(yearToSelect, Seq("year", "row_number")).drop("row_number")
```

Edit:
Added the third approach for posterity using Dataset API's - groupByKey and mapGroups:

```
//encoding to data class can be avoided if inputDF is not converted dataset of row objects
val outputDF = inputDF.as[data].groupByKey(_.year).mapGroups{ case (year, rows) =>
      val itemsSortedByMonth = rows.toSeq.sortBy(_.month).map(s => items(s.item, s.quantity))
      (year, itemsSortedByMonth)
    }.toDF("year", "items")
```

Comment: Good stuff, was trying to avoid UDF, second one not sure I would have come up with.

Comment: I have tried third approach, it worked perfectly. Thanks for solutions

Comment: Thanks, @thebluephantom.  Any reason for avoiding UDF?

Comment: @s1705 added third approach code for posterity. Happy it worked for you :)

Comment: Also posted an even easier answer.

Comment: @user2526641 I believe approaches 1 and 3 are almost the same from Spark's execution point of view. It is just the comfortability of different APIs. As a Scala developer, I prefer 3.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was looking for an approach without an UDF. That was OK except for once aspect that I could not solve elegantly. With a simple map UDF it is extremely simple, simpler than the other answers. So, for posterity and a little later due to other commitments.

Try this...

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class abc(year: Int, month: Int, item: String, quantity: Int)
val itemsList= collect_list(struct("month", "item", "quantity"))

val my_udf = udf { items: Seq[Row] =>  
                   val res = items.map { r => (r.getAs[String](1), r.getAs[Int](2)) }
                   res
                 }
// Gen some data, however, not the thrust of the problem.
val df0 = Seq(abc(2019, 1, "TV", 8), abc(2019, 7, "AC", 10), abc(2018, 1, "TV", 2), abc(2018, 2, "AC", 3), abc(2019, 2, "CO", 7)).toDS()
val df1 = df0.toDF()

val df2 = df1.groupBy($"year")
             .agg(itemsList as "items")
             .withColumn("sortedCol", sort_array($"items", asc = true))
             .withColumn("sortedItems", my_udf(col("sortedCol") ))
             .drop("items").drop("sortedCol")
             .orderBy($"year".desc)

df2.show(false)
df2.printSchema()
```

Noting the following that you should fix:

- order by later is better imho
- mistakes in data (fixed now)
- ordering mth by String is not a good idea, need to convert to mth num

Returns:

```
+----+----------------------------+
|year|sortedItems                 |
+----+----------------------------+
|2019|[[TV, 8], [CO, 7], [AC, 10]]|
|2018|[[TV, 2], [AC, 3]]          |
+----+----------------------------+
```

Comment: I think, collect_set will remove duplicates in the data set, not the duplicate rows

Comment: look at the answer, note the output and the groupBy, there is both collect_set and collect_list

Comment: sorry, for the mistakes in the dataset, I have corrected it now.
I have tried to run the code which you have shared, but I am facing below error

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression '`item`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (

Comment: works for me. paste yr cde below in totality and i will check

Comment: I think u missed considering partition window..... In some of blogs I read using group and collect_list may not follow the order by properly..

Comment: thanks for reminding me, but also note my first bullet...and practical observation and own research before question is also a good approach...