# Iterating over for an Array Column with dynamic size in Spark Scala Dataframe

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am familiar with this approach - case in point an example from [How to obtain the average of an array-type column in scala-spark over all row entries per entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532225/how-to-obtain-the-average-of-an-array-type-column-in-scala-spark-over-all-row-en/59532979#59532979)

```
val array_size = 3
val avgAgg = for (i <- 0 to array_size -1) yield avg($"value".getItem(i))
df.select(array(avgAgg: _*).alias("avg_value")).show(false)
```

However, the 3 is hard-coded in reality.

No matter how hard I try not to use an UDF, I cannot do this type of thing dynamically based on the size of an array column already present in the data frame. E.g:

```
...
val z =  for (i <- 1 to size($"sortedCol")   ) yield array (element_at($"sortedCol._2", i), element_at($"sortedCol._3", i) )
...
...
.withColumn("Z", array(z: _*)  )
```

I am looking as to how this can be done by applying to an existing array col which is variable in length. transform, expr? Not sure.

Full code as per request:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

case class abc(year: Int, month: Int, item: String, quantity: Int)

val df0 = Seq(abc(2019, 1, "TV", 8), 
              abc(2019, 7, "AC", 10),  
              abc(2018, 1, "TV", 2),  
              abc(2018, 2, "AC", 3), 
              abc(2019, 2, "CO", 10)).toDS()

val df1 = df0.toDF()
// Gen some data, can be done easier, but not the point.

val itemsList= collect_list(struct("month", "item", "quantity"))

// This nn works.
val nn = 3
val z =  for (i <- 1 to nn) yield array (element_at($"sortedCol.item", i), element_at($"sortedCol.quantity", i) )
// But want this.
//val z =  for (i <- 1 to size($"sortedCol")   ) yield array (element_at($"sortedCol.item", i), element_at($"sortedCol.quantity", i) )


val df2 = df1.groupBy($"year")
   .agg(itemsList as "items")
   .withColumn("sortedCol", sort_array($"items", asc = true))  
   .withColumn("S", size($"sortedCol")) // cannot use this either
   .withColumn("Z", array(z: _*)  )
   .drop("items")
   .orderBy($"year".desc)
df2.show(false)
// Col Z is the output I want, but not the null value Array
```

**UPD**

[In apache spark SQL, how to remove the duplicate rows when using collect_list in window function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61318531/in-apache-spark-sql-how-to-remove-the-duplicate-rows-when-using-collect-list-in/61319420#61319420) there I solve with a very simple UDF but I was looking for a way without UDF and in particular the dynamic setting of the `to value` in the `for loop`. The answer proves that certain constructs are not possible - which was the verification being sort.

Comment: @blackbishop Any ideas here? What am I missing

Comment: @LeoC interested in your insights

Comment: If all the arrays have the same size then you can first get it like this : `val array_size = df.select(size($"sortedCol")).first.getInt(0)`. The rest of the code remains the same.

Comment: @blackbishop But that is exactly the point, they do not. I noted your solution and I applied this aspect in the past or took a high default and dropped null values generated. But I am wondering why the issue exists. Seems a pretty common 'enough' use case.

Comment: OK, I see now. Could you add a reproductible example to the question please?

Comment: @blackbishop  OK will do, but not using an UDF. Cannot see why so difficult get the typical col error!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your need, you can simply use `transform` function like this:

```
val df2 = df1.groupBy($"year")
             .agg(itemsList as "items")
             .withColumn("sortedCol", sort_array($"items", asc = true))


val transform_expr = "transform(sortedCol, x -> array(x.item, x.quantity))"

df2.withColumn("Z", expr(transform_expr)).show(false)

//+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
//|year|items                                 |sortedCol                             |Z                            |
//+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
//|2018|[[1, TV, 2], [2, AC, 3]]              |[[1, TV, 2], [2, AC, 3]]              |[[TV, 2], [AC, 3]]           |
//|2019|[[1, TV, 8], [7, AC, 10], [2, CO, 10]]|[[1, TV, 8], [2, CO, 10], [7, AC, 10]]|[[TV, 8], [CO, 10], [AC, 10]]|
//+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: OK, I did that with a UDF as opposed to transform which amounts to the same thing essentially. But the crus of my question was can we ever have something like val z =  for (i <- 1 to size($"sortedCol") ... or is that just not allowed?

Comment: Answer is allocated, but I am looking for the above point in a particular manner. Maybe it is a red herring because of the alternatives.

Comment: @thebluephantom When you do `z = for (i <- 1 to size($"sortedCol"))`, you're trying to use a Scala for-comprehension but you give a Spark Column in the enumerator. It's just not possible to do that... Because the Column is evaluated under a Spark DF and not with Scala.